# Google groups CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-groups, google-groups-settings

[Google groups settings SDK](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/groupssettings/v1/python/latest/groupssettings_v1.groups.html) ([python](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/groupssettings/v1/python/latest/groupssettings_v1.groups.html)) doesn't seem to make a difference between "*Anyone can ask*" and "*Anyone in the organisation can ask*" to join permissions.

The `whoCanJoin` permission parameter only allows the following values :
`ANYONE_CAN_JOIN ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_JOIN INVITED_CAN_JOIN CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN`

When I set the permission to `CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN`, only the setting "*Anyone in the organisation can ask*" gets checked.

[image: Groups whoCanJoin]

Even when I manualy check the "*Anyone can ask*" permission. The settings JSON stays the same :

`{u'allowExternalMembers': u'true',
 u'allowGoogleCommunication': u'false',
 u'allowWebPosting': u'true',
 u'archiveOnly': u'false',
 u'customFooterText': u'',
 u'customReplyTo': u'',
 u'defaultMessageDenyNotificationText': u'',
 u'description': u"---------",
 u'email': u'---------@orga.com',
 u'includeCustomFooter': u'false',
 u'includeInGlobalAddressList': u'true',
 u'isArchived': u'false',
 u'kind': u'groupsSettings#groups',
 u'maxMessageBytes': 26214400,
 u'membersCanPostAsTheGroup': u'false',
 u'messageDisplayFont': u'DEFAULT_FONT',
 u'messageModerationLevel': u'MODERATE_NONE',
 u'name': u'----------',
 u'replyTo': u'REPLY_TO_IGNORE',
 u'sendMessageDenyNotification': u'false',
 u'showInGroupDirectory': u'false',
 u'spamModerationLevel': u'MODERATE',
 u'whoCanAdd': u'ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_ADD',
 u'whoCanContactOwner': u'ANYONE_CAN_CONTACT',
 u'whoCanInvite': u'ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_INVITE',
 u'whoCanJoin': u'CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN',
 u'whoCanLeaveGroup': u'ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_LEAVE',
 u'whoCanPostMessage': u'ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST',
 u'whoCanViewGroup': u'ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW',
 u'whoCanViewMembership': u'ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_VIEW'}`

Would anyone know how to programmaticaly set this setting to both "*Anyone can ask*" **and** "*Anyone in the organisation can ask*" ?

Comment: Can you update your question with a minimal and reproducible example that reproduces this behaviour please? This will assist people that may be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, it must be done in two commands : First allow external members, then set whoCanJoin settings and other rights.

Setting both in one settings body doesn't work.

```
def set_settings(self, group_mail, settings, batch=None):
    req = self.service.groups().update(
        groupUniqueId=group_mail,
        body=settings)

    if batch:
        batch.add(req)
    else:
        req.execute()

def allow_external_members(self, group_mail, batch=None):
    self.set_settings(group_mail, {"allowExternalMembers": "true"}, batch)

def allow_join_request(self, group_mail, batch=None):
    self.set_settings(group_mail, {"whoCanJoin": "CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN"}, batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would anyone know how to programmaticaly set this setting to both
>   "Anyone can ask" and "Anyone in the organisation can ask" ?

You're asking how to set the `whoCanJoin` property so that "Anyone can ask" and "Anyone in the organisation can ask"?

The answer is to set the `whoCanJoin` property to `CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN`. You don't need to (and cannot) set it to multiple values because this single value ensures that ***anyone***, including those in your organisation, can ask to join.

Here is a link to the documentation for the underlying [Group Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource).

Comment: As I said, setting the `whoCanJoin` setting to `CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN` only checks "Anyone in the organisation can ask". It does not check "Anyone can ask" as I wished.